# Calculating difference in seconds

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I'm calculating time differences, in seconds, between busses' expected and actual stop times.

My problem looks like this:

```
# creating data
d = {
    'time_A': ['2022-08-30 06:21:00', '2022-08-30 16:41:00'], 
    'time_B': ['2022-08-30 06:21:09', '2022-08-30 16:40:16'], 
}

# creating DataFrame
my_df = pd.DataFrame(d)
my_df['time_A'] = pd.to_datetime(my_df['time_A'])
my_df['time_B'] = pd.to_datetime(my_df['time_B'])

# subtracting times
my_df['difference'] = my_df['time_B'] - my_df['time_A']

my_df
```

result:

```
    time_A  time_B  difference
0   2022-08-30 06:21:00 2022-08-30 06:21:09 0 days 00:00:09
1   2022-08-30 16:41:00 2022-08-30 16:40:16 -1 days +23:59:16
```

I don't understand why the difference between today 16:40:16 and today 16:41:00 is *-1 days +23:59:16*.

if I do this

```
my_df['difference'] = (my_df['time_B'] - my_df['time_A']).dt.seconds
```

Then I get

```
    time_A  time_B  difference
0   2022-08-30 06:21:00 2022-08-30 06:21:09 9
1   2022-08-30 16:41:00 2022-08-30 16:40:16 86356
```

I would like the "difference" cell on row O to display something like "+9", and the one below to display "-44".
How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: TRy `(my_df['time_B'] - my_df['time_A']) / pd.Timedelta('1s')`?

Comment: or also `(my_df['time_B'] - my_df['time_A']).dt.total_seconds()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtracting `datetime.datetime`s gives [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)s which are represented that way, use `.total_seconds()` to get numeric value of seconds, consider following simple example

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"schedule":pd.to_datetime(["2000-01-01 12:00:00"]),"actual":pd.to_datetime(["2000-01-01 12:00:05"])})
df['difference_sec'] = (df['schedule'] - df['actual']).apply(datetime.timedelta.total_seconds)
print(df)
```

output

```
             schedule              actual  difference_sec
0 2000-01-01 12:00:00 2000-01-01 12:00:05            -5.0
```

Note that this is feature of `datetime.timedelta`, it is not specific to `pandas`.